# IP Assignment for WAN and LAN Interface:

Tags: networking, ip, lan, subnet, wan

Very Much confused about assigning IP address to WAN Interface and LAN Interface on Router/Firewall. 
I know the process of assigning IP address but don't know which IP address to assign. Support My default gateway for ISP is 14.141.46.129, then what IP should I assign to my WAN Interface? And what Subnet Mask I have to assign?

Now What IP address I should assign to LAN Interface? And what Subnet Mask I have to assign?

After Assigning IP, I have to get Internet access from My LAN interface to WAN Interface.....

How to find the route to WAN Interface so that I Can ping google.com??

Comment: This depends on several things.  Is your ISP giving you a static address range?  If a static range, how big?

Answer (score 0):

First, 14.141.46.129 is a valid IP address. The WAN interface needs a public IP address which should be given by your ISP provider.you can covert through cyberoam interface A port for-wan, B port for local lan & new range of 192.168.2.1 to 192.168.2.255 subnet mask 255.255.255.0 as u need you have to covert in subnetmask 192.168.2.1/32 to as per your needing (You assing your local ip for Lan The LAN interface can be in the range 192.168.2.2-254 with a mask of 255.255.255.0, )

Answer (score -1):

First, 14.141.46.129 is not a valid IP address.
The WAN interface needs a public IP address which should be given by your ISP provider.
The LAN interface can be in the range 192.168.1.2-254 with a mask of 255.255.255.0

Comment: 14.141.46.129 is a perfectly valid IPv4 address.